# ¿Por qué decimos "esta bolsa 'está' rota" y no 'es'?

Tags: gramática, cópulas

¿Por qué no puede usar "es" en vez de "estar" en esta frase?

> Esta bolsa **está** rota.

Comment: For the first one I'm guessing because broken is not an inherent quality of a bag we must use estar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between ser/estar resides in the transitiveness of the adjective.

I am a man, and that is not going to change, so:

> Soy un hombre

I am sitting on my computer, but I can stand up:

> Estoy sentado en mi ordenador.

La bolsa está rota, pero antes estaba sana. 
Es una bolsa, y siempre será una bolsa.

Please read about transitive and intransitive states.

Answer (score 0):

"Está" habla de un estado físico, "ser" es más para cualidades de los objetos.

> La bolsa está fea.
>
> La bolsa es amarilla.

Comment: la bolsa puede ser fea si hace una generalización, verdad?

Comment: @Drew Sí, claro.  «la bolsa es fea» (su diseño es horrible), «la bolsa está fea» (sin contemplar su diseño, está tachada o manchada, hay que arreglarla o limpiarla)